# Autocorrelation of a random process

Tags: autocorrelation, random-process, signal-energy

I have some doubt about the following exercise.

> Let's consider the signal $X(t)= \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2A}\right) $ , where $A$ is a
> discrete random variable which can assume one value between ${2,4,8}$
> with equal probability and $$\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2A}\right)= \begin{cases} 1 , &
> > \text{if} -A < t < A \newline 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
> Find:
>
> 1. The pmf of X(t) ;
> 2. The Energy spectral density (ESD) ;
> 3. The autocorrelation function.

What I did is

1. $p(x;t) = \begin{cases} 
   \operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{4}) , Pr(A=2)= \frac{1}{3}
   \newline
   \operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{8}) , Pr(A=4) = \frac{1}{3}
   \newline
   \operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{16}) ,Pr(A=8)= \frac{1}{3}
   \end{cases}$
2. $\mathcal{E}_x(f)= E[X^2(t)] = \frac{1}{3} [\operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{4}) + \operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{8}) + \operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{16})] $
3. The autocorrelation function of the random process is $$R_x(t. \tau) = E[X(t)X(t- \tau)] = E\left[\operatorname{rect}\left( \frac{t}{2A}\right) \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t- \tau}{2A}\right)\right].$$ How do I go on from here?

Edit:
If we reason in terms of "events" Ev, when is $X(t)=1$ ? We have that:

1. if $  |t| \leq 2 , P(X(t)=1)=P(X(t)=1 | A=2 \cup A=4 \cup A=8) =1 $
2. if $2<|t| \leq 4  , P(X(t)=1)=P(X(t)=1 | A=4 \cup A=8) = \frac{2}{3} $
3. if $4<|t| \leq 8, P(X(t)=1)=P(X(t)=1 | A=8) = \frac{1}{3} $
4. if $|t| \geq 8, P(X(t)=1)=P(X(t)=1 | \emptyset) = 0 $
   So, if I want the pmf of $X(t)$, I can simply pick the pmf of one of the Bernoulli variables? Can I not characterize $X(t)$ as a whole?

In regards to the autocorrelation function, $R_X(t,s)= E[X(t)X(s)]$ :
if (t,s) are part of the same interval (i.e. B,C,D,E), the autocorrelation function is equal to the mean square value of $X(t)$ , while if they're part of different intervals the ACF is equal to the product of the means, am I correct?

Comment: If you want to write a single formula for the pmf of $X(t)$ that applies for all $t$, go for it. It will be a mess to read and understand and I refuse to help you in the least in constructing this monstrosity.<br>
It would probably help the reader if you define what the sets $B, C, D, E$, are in your question itself.<br>
You are _not_ correct in what you ask in the last sentence of your question. Read my answer very carefully; it specifies exactly what the ACF is, and it is _not_ the product of the means in general.

Comment: Are you sure that $X(t)$ can be a Bernoulli random variable? $X(t)$ is a continuous random variable, while a bernoullian one is discrete.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that for each and every choice of real number $t$, $X(t)$ is a discrete random variable; in. fact a Bernoulli random variable.  It is $t$ that is a continuous random variable. Your question calls the whole of DSP into question because you seem to be insisting that all functions of continuous variable $t$ are themselves necessarily continuous functions, thus denying the existence of things like the rect function which you yourself are using, and square waves etc.

Comment: If two random variables are independent, isn't their correlation function equal to the product of their means? If $t,s$ are part of different intervals, $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ should be independent. So we also have that the ACF is equal to $\frac{2}{9}$ , no?

Comment: Please define exactly what **you** mean by correlation because with the commonly accepted meaning of the word "correlation" with regard to random _variables_, it is _not_ true that the correlation of _independent_ random variables equals the product of the means: *independent random variables are* **uncorrelated** *meaning that their correlation is* $0$ *regardless of what their means are.*  Also $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ are _not_ independent: even if $t$ and $s$ belong to different intervals. The second part of my answer spent quite some time explaining why. Please _read_ the answer carefully.

Comment: Followup questions should be asked separately. I see lots of subquestions and lots of subanswers, it's unfocused now.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's working is incorrect, and proceeding further from what is included in the OP's question will not help in the least.

A random process is a *collection* of random variables all having a family name such as $X$ and being identified within the family by subscripts such as $X_t$ or arguments such as $X(t)$. In the OP's (homework?) problem, the (infinitely many) random variables $X(t)$ all are discrete random variables, in fact, Bernoulli random variables with different parameters. Since $A$ is a discrete random variable taking on values $2,4,8$ with equal probability $\frac 13$, $X(t)= \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2A}\right)$ has value $1$ for $t \in (-2,2)$, for $t \in (-4,4)$, and $t\in (-8,8)$ respectively, with equal probability $\frac 13$; and $X(t)$ has value $0$ if $|t| \geq 8.$ Let's look at this information a little more closely.

Define sets $B, C, D, E$ of real numbers as follows:
\begin{align}
B &= \{t\colon |t| \geq 8\},\\
C &= \{t\colon 4 \leq |t| < 8\}.\\
D &= \{t\colon 2 \leq |t| < 4\},\\
E &= \{t\colon  |t| < 2\}
\end{align}
and note that every real number belongs to one and only one of the sets $B,C,D,E$. Corresponding to these sets of real numbers, define real numbers (parameters) $p_B, p_C, p_D, p_E$ as $0,\frac 13,\frac 23, 1$ respectively.

Now, suppose that $t$ is a real number in set $C$. What can we say about $X(t)$? Well, clearly, $X(t) = \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2A}\right)$ has value $1$ if and only if $A=8$ which event has probability $\frac 13$ of occurring.
We conclude that

> For all $t \in C$, that is, for all $t$ such that $4 \leq |t| < 8$, $X(t)$ is a  *Bernoulli* random variable with parameter $p_C = \frac 13$.

Next, suppose that $t$ is a real number in set $D$. What can we say about $X(t)$? Well, clearly,
$X(t) = \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2A}\right)$ has value $1$ if and only if $A=8$ or $A=4$ which event has probability $\frac 23$ of occurring.
We conclude that

> For all $t \in D$, that is, for all $t$ such that $2 \leq |t| < 4$, $X(t)$ is a  *Bernoulli* random variable with parameter $p_D = \frac 23$.

If $t \in E$, that is, $|t| < 2$, then $X(t)$ has value $1$ regardless of what value $A$ has; it is a constant! But we fit this into the Procrustean bed of Bernoulli random variables by saying

> For all $t \in E$, that is, for all $t$ such that $|t| < 2$, $X(t)$ is a  *Bernoulli* random variable with parameter $p_E = 1$.

Similarly, if $t \in B$, that is, $|t| \geq 8$, then $X(t)$ has value $0$ regardless of what value $A$ has. We fit this also into our Procrustean bed of Bernoulli random variables by saying

> For all $t \in E$, that is, for all $t$ such that $|t| \geq 8$, $X(t)$ is a  *Bernoulli* random variable with parameter $p_B = 0$.

Summarizing, $p_X(x;t)$, the pmf of $X(t)$, is the pmf of a Bernoulli random variable with parameter respectively $p_B, p_C, p_D,p_E$ (a.k.a. $0,\frac 13,\frac 23, 1$) according as $t$ is in sets $B, C, D, E$. Note that each of the four possible pmfs for $X(t)$ *is* a valid pmf: the values of $P(X(t)= 1)$ and $P(X(t)=0)$ sum to $1$ ($0+1=1, \frac 23 + \frac 13 = 1, \frac 13 + \frac 23 = 1, 1+0 = 1$ as the case may be) but I cheerfully admit that $0,\frac 13,\frac 23, 1$ don't add up to $1$. Why should they? Those numbers are just the four possible *parameters* of the Bernoulli pmf, not the pmf values!

It is worth emphasizing that the random variable**s** $X(t)$ are *very* dependent, in fact, *identical* over various intervals. For example, *all* $X(t)$ for $t \in C$ must take on the *same* value ($0$ or $1$ as the case may be); it is not possible for, say $X(5.1)$, to have value $1$ while $X(6)$ has value $0$. Even worse, if the random variables $\{X(t) \colon 4 \leq |t| < 8\}$ all have value $1$, then the random variables $\{X(t)\colon 2 \leq |t| < 4\}$ *also* must *all* have value $1$ while if $\{X(t)\colon 4 \leq |t| < 8\}$ all have value $0$, then $\{X(t)\colon 2 \leq |t| < 4\}$ could have value either $0$ or $1$. Thus, any $X(t\colon t \in C)$ and any $X(t\colon t \in D)$ are *not* independent random variables.

Now, since all the $X(t\colon t \in E)$ are *degenerate* random variables that take on value $1$ with probability $1$ (and thus are identical too), it must be admitted that they also are *independent* random variables, since for $t_1, t_2 \in E$, $$P(X(t_1)=1,X(t_2)=1)= 1 = P(X(t_1)=1)P(X(t_2)=1).$$
Heck, since we haven't excluded the possibility that $t_1=t_2$, $X(t_1)$ *is independent of itself too!* Similarly, though the $X(t\colon t \in B)$ are *degenerate* random variables that take on value $0$ with probability $1$ (and thus are identical too), it must be admitted that they also are *independent* random variables, since for $t_1, t_2 \in E$, $$P(X(t_1)=0,X(t_2)=0)= 1 = P(X(t_1)=0)P(X(t_2)=0).$$ Similar arguments can be made about $X(t\colon t \in E)$ and $X(t\colon t \in B\cup C\cup D)$, and about $X(t\colon t \in B)$ and $X(t\colon t \in C\cup D \cup E)$, but it is *not* possible to claim (as the OP wishes to do) that in *all cases*, random variables in different intervals are independent. The counterexample is provided in the previous paragraph: any $X(t\colon t \in C)$ and any $X(t\colon t \in D)$ are *not* independent random variables.

---

Turning to the autocorrelation function $R_X(t,s) = \mathbb E[X(t)X(s)]$, we need to evaluate this expectation for all pairs of real numbers $(t,s)$ where $t$ and $s$ each belong to $B$ or $C$ or $D$ or $E$. There are $16$ possible cases to consider, Let's denote by $G$ the set ($B$ or $C$ or $D$ or $E$) to which $t$ belongs; and by $H$ the set ($B$ or $C$ or $D$ or $E$) to which $s$ belongs.

- If either $G$ or $H$ is $B$ (possibly both are $B$), then at least one of $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ is $0$ and so $R_X(t,s) = \mathbb E[X(t)X(s)] = \mathbb E[0] = 0$. Note that this is saying that $R_X(t,s)$ has value $0$ whenever at least one of $t$ and $s$ has *magnitude* $8$ or more, that is, the point $(t,s)$ lies on or outside the boundary of the $16\times 16$ square centered at the origin (and sides parallel to the axes). Thus, the nonzero values of $R_X(t,s)$ occur only in the interior of this $16\times 16$ square. Note also that one way of specifying the value of $R_X(t,s)$ in this region is $R_X(t,s) = \min(p_G, p_H)$ since at least one of $G$ and $H$ is $B$ and so at least one of $p_G, p_H$ is $0$.
- If both $G$ and $H$ are $E$, then both $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ are $1$ and so $$R_X(t,s) = \mathbb E[1] = 1 = \min(p_G, p_H),$$  Thus, $R_X(t,s) = 1$ if $(t,s)$ lies in the *interior* of the $4\times 4$ square centered to the origin.
- Next, consider the *hollow-square* region consisting of all points $(t,s)$ lying in the interior of the $8\times 8$ square but on or outside the boundary of the $4\times 4$ square. Here, at least one of $G$ and $H$ is $D$ (the other can be $D$ or $E$.) If the other is $E$, then one of $X(t), X(s)$ has value $1$ and so $\mathbb E[X(t)X(s)]= p_D$. If both $G$ and $H$ are $D$, then $X(t)X(s)$ has value $1$ with probability $p_D$. Thus, in this hollow-square region also, we have that
  $$\mathbb E[X(t)X(s)]= p_D = \frac 23 = \min(p_G, p_H).$$
- Finally, consider the *hollow-square* region consisting of all points $(t,s)$ lying in the interior of the $16\times 16$ square but on or outside the boundary of the $8\times 8$ square. Here, at least one of $G$ and $H$ is $C$ (the other can be $C$ or $D$ or $E$.) Using the same type of arguments as above, we get that
  $$\mathbb E[X(t)X(s)]= p_C = \frac 13 = \min(p_G, p_H).$$

> In summary, $R_X(t,s)$ is nonzero only in the interior of the $16\times 16$ square with sides parallel to the axes and center the origin.
> In the $4\times 4$ central square, $R_X(t,s)$ has constant value $1$.
> In the hollow-square region consisting of the $8\times 8$ square *less* the $4\times 4$ square, $R_X(t,s)$ has constant value $\frac 23$. 
> In the hollow-square region consisting of the $16\times 16$ square *less* the $8\times 8$ square, $R_X(t,s)$ has constant value $\frac 13$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer. I understand the first half of your answer but not the second half. The pmf of a discrete random variable is the sum of masses of probability and the total is equal to 1, right?

Comment: Sorry about the bad notation. I have revised the notation and the answer thoroughly and hope that it makes more sense now.  I will complete the autocorrelation stuff later today.